# Fatal error: Unable to get your client ID

Tags: ios, uber-api

I am using the Uber API and I did change my `info.Plist` but it's not recognizing the name apparently, I passed it the client ID I received from the developer dashboard.

**Error in the Debugger:**

```
Unable to locate application icon fatal error: Unable to get your ClientID. 
Did you forget to set it in your Info.plist? (Should be under UberClientID key)
```

[image: error in the debugger]

Answer (score 3):

Your info.plist does not look right. The  fields need to be the keys that the SDK can recognize. So for example, if my client ID was "my_client_id_123" and my redirect URI was "myapp://login" then my .plist would look something like this:

```
<key>UberClientID</key>
<string>my_client_id_123</string>
<key>UberCallbackURIs</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UberCallbackURIType</key>
        <string>General</string>
        <key>URIString</key>
        <string>myapp://login</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

(I also wouldn't suggest posting your actual Client ID on the internet)

Comment: thank you,  you are right that fixed the problem  yeah, i will delete the pictures of client ID